# Length of the largest chain of a poset ordered by set inclusion.

Tags: order-theory, equivalence-relations, set-partition

If $E4$ is the set of all equivalence relations on $\{1,2,3,4\}$,and we define a poset as

> $(E4, \{(R1,R2) \in E4 \times E4 \mid R1 \subseteq R2\})$

then what would be the length of largest chain of this poset?

Comment: It would be $4$. I think it's easiest to calculate by considering equivalence classes. Then two equivalence relations are subsets of each other, if one comes from refinement of the other.

Comment: ya but does that mean that height of this poset is 4?

Comment: That's the *definition* of the height, so yes.